# Как убрать последний столбец в ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Вывожу список в ListView и постоянно этот столбец откуда-то появляется. В этом и вопрос, как его отключить?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Guess.Yourself.QuestionView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Guess.Yourself"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Архив вопросов" 
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    Topmost="True"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="lv" Background="Gray" Height="300" MaxHeight="300" MinWidth="250" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
        <!--<ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="32" Foreground="White"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>-->
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Вопросы">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="32" Foreground="White"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Да">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainWindowViewModel}">
                            <Button Command="{Binding YesCmd}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Нет">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainWindowViewModel}">
                            <Button Command="{Binding NoCmd}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Не знаю">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainWindowViewModel}">
                            <Button Command="{Binding DontKnowCmd}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Вот так это выглядит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: После столбца "Не знаю" идёт пустой столбец. В разметке у меня нет его. Магия какая-то.

Comment: Это не столбец, это просто пустое место, потому что суммарная ширина всех ваших колонок меньше, чем ширина самого `ListView`.

Comment: @aepot Уже нагуглил это. Думалось, что весь контент будет масштабироваться  под размер всего ListView. Убрал MinWidth и ситуация поправилась, но в целом осталось непонимание ситуации, если мне нужно изменять размеры строк с названием хэдэров или менять отступы, то они не меняются.

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, не относящийся к изначальному. Но если что-то не меняется, значит вы пока не нашли правильный способ это сделать. Я уверен на 100%, что здесь никаких ограничений по адаптивным размерам колонок или контролов нет. Иногда бывает не просто сделать как хочется, но возможно всегда.

Comment: @aepot Ответ оформите, плс, чтобы люди сразу находили нужную инфу. К слову, чтобы изменить в нужных мне местах Padding, Margin - пришлось перерыть весь шаблон ListView, который используется по-умолчанию.

Comment: Этот ответ настолько очевиден, что я даже раньше вопросов подобных не видел (а разработчиков, которые сталкиваются с всякого рода таблицами - оочень много). Думаю, нет нужды в оформлении ответа.

Comment: Вру, все-таки нашел [один](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215068/remove-the-blank-column-in-a-wpf-datagrid) такой же вопрос.

Comment: @aepot у начинающих могут возникнуть такие вопросы)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убрал св-во MinWidth у ListView и свободное пространство слева исчезло.

Answer (score 0):

Для последнего столбца width="*" тогда он займет все оставшееся место.

Comment: Не работает для столбцов ListView определение ширины таким образом width = "*"